# What simple formal systems are there that have behavior similar to actual chemistry?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I've been doing reading about formal/axiomatic chemistry and am wondering: are there attempts at making formal systems (well defined rules that can be simulated on a computer) that have similar emergent behavior to real world chemistry in some way?

Clearly this would be very difficult for reproducing all of the physics of matter but I haven't been able to find any papers about attempts to make simple systems that have meaningful 3D interactions besides cellular automata which are very different.

Comment: Well, there's lots of stuff. I guess you're talking about macroscopic behaviour? CA is only one of ways and not so different from modelling for example with differential equations.

Comment: Yea I know at microscopic/quantum levels they've had to get more formal and there are some detailed things like this so yea I'm really asking about introductory chemistry type things you might study, things on a more macroscopic scale

Comment: The system is inherently chaotic and probabilistic. There is no way to model it in the way you would like to. But in the case of statistical mechanics, we compute and derive macroscopic quantities from microscopic ones in aggregate. This is probably as close as you can get.

Comment: You may be interested in searching for Synergetics by H. Haken roughly defined as emergent phenomena as found in non-equilibrium phase transitions and self organisation in physics , chemistry and biology.

Comment: This is a really great question, but it's unfortunately too broad to be a good fit to the format of the site.

Comment: @hBy2Py Where do you recommend asking it/how could it be tweaked to fit this format?

Comment: I don't know if would be possible to modify it to fit, unfortunately. Per the logic laid out on meta [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653), questions of the "I'm looking for a thing that is *X*" is intrinsically open-ended, leading to numerous possible valid answers and/or opinion-based discussion, rather than a targeted, closed-scope, definitive answer. It would probably be best raised on chat, either in the [main room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table) or in a new room dedicated to the topic.

Comment: While I see what you mean, this question has enough votes that signifies that people are interested in it, and chat doesn't provide a good resource for googlers or people that have similar questions. In my mind, if a question has enough interest and doesn't have somewhere it can be asked that more fits that environment, it should be allowed to stay because it will be useful to others that have similar questions since that is the point of the site.

Comment: I'm okay with turning this into, say, a community wiki though

Answer (score 2):

The Lewis model (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3285721/) meets those criteria.

Comment: I went to the [site of one of the authors of that paper](http://people.brandeis.edu/~herzfeld/forces.html) and it provided a ton of great similar things

Comment: For the benefit of those who don't have access to the article, could you provide a summary of its contents? As relevant as it may be, on Stack Exchange we try not to encourage answers that only contain a link.